# $geoNear requires a 2d or 2dSphere index but none were found

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the problem i got stucked while working with the geoJson data .I would like to thanks in advance if someone ca point the solution for me.

**Schema  ** Added a 2dsphere as index inside the coordinates but still not working

```
const polygonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type:String,
  properties: {
    REGTYPE_ID: Number,
    REGTYPE: String,
    NAVWAT_ID: Number,
    Shape_Leng: Number,
    Shape_Area: Number
  },
  geometry: {
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      index: '2dsphere',
      required: true
    },
    type: {
      enum: ["Polygon"]

    }
  }
});
polygonSchema.index({ geometry: '2dsphere' }, { background: false })
const Polygon = mongoose.model("Polygon", polygonSchema);

exports.polygonSchema = polygonSchema;
exports.Polygon = Polygon;
```

***Route*** Can somereview is the below query correct?

````
  // console.log(req.query);
  try {
    Polygon.aggregate([
      {
        $geoNear: {
          near: {
            type: "Feature",
            // geometry: {
              coordinates: [
                parseFloat(req.query.lng),
                parseFloat(req.query.lat)
              ]
            // }
          },
           distanceField: "geometry.distance",
          maxDistance: 10000,
          spherical: true
        }
      }
    ]).then(function(Locs) {
      res.send(Locs);
    });
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
  }
});```

***Error Stack Trace*** the stack trace shows that a geoNear requireees 2d or 2dsphere but i even done it in my model




```(node:4928) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: $geoNear requires a 2d or 2dsphere index, but none were found```
````

Comment: I don't think "feature" is a supported GeoJSON type.

Comment: even changing a type to a polygon results a same error stack